# Property of a continuous convex function with additional properties

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and convex function such that $f(0)=0$ and $\int\limits_0^1 f(x) ~dx=0$. Prove that
$$\int\limits_0^1 |f(x)| ~dx=2\cdot \max\limits_{x\in [0,1]}\left|\int\limits_0^x f(t) ~dt\right|.$$

For now I considered just the simpler case when $f(1)\leq 0$. Since a convex function defined on a closed interval attains its maximum on one end of the interval and since $f(0)=0$, it follows that $f(x)\leq 0$ on $[0,1]$; therefore, the function $\int\limits_0^x f(t)~dt$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$, but since its values in $0$ and $1$ are both $0$ this function is constant ($0$) on the whole interval and the conclusion follows easily.

Comment: If you consider f(1) ≤ 0, then f ≤ 0 on [0,1], and so the integral won't be 0

Comment: @user398843: $f$ can still be identically zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
a = \max \{ x \in [0, 1] \mid f(x) \le 0 \}
$$
is well-defined since $f(0) = 0$ and $f$ is continuous. Then $f(x) \le 0$ on $[0, a]$ (since $f$ is convex), and $f(x) > 0$ on $(a, 1]$.

The function $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$ is decreasing on $[0, a]$ and increasing on $[a, 1]$ with $F(0) = F(1) = 0$. Now we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 |f(x)| \, dx &= \int_0^a (-f(x)) \, dx + \int_a^1 f(x) \, dx \\
&= -(F(a)-F(0) + F(1)-F(a) \\
&= -2 F(a)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
 \max_{x \in [0, 1]} |F(x)| = \max_{x \in [0, 1]} (-F(x)) = -F(a) \, .
$$

Comment: I'm not sure I can "see" now the rigurous argument for the fact that $f(x)\leq 0$ on $[0,a]$, even if everything seems intuitively alright. I will think about it. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyC: $f$ is convex with $f(0) = f(a) = 0$, so what can you tell about $f$ on $(0, a)$?

Comment: pff, you're right, I have used this argument myself... :) actually, it is enough if $f(a)\leq 0$